# Server name in URL for internet sites

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Having an issue with my new SharePoint 2016 site.  Very new to this and untrained so be patient.  :)

Oh and forgive the spaces in the URL links below, I had to put them in because I was allowed here to post links

Ok I've set up SharePoint and created the Farm, Collection Sites on the default web application (port 80) as per all the information I could find etc all on hpsd-bdc.  I've gone into the AAM and set up the following:

- Default: http://hpsd-bdc
- Internet: https://sp.hpsd.com.au

I've gone into Bindings in IIS and and added both http on port 80 and https on port 443.

Now... issue being is that most links on the external internet site are pointing back to hpsd-bdc on the newsfeed or any MySites.  All links are pointing to `http://hpsd-bdc/my/` instead of `https://sp.hpsd.com.au/my`. If I click on the link, then manually change the URL to the `sp.hpsd.com.au` one it works no worries, but obviously you don't want to do that every time.

So... what have I missed?  What have I done wrong?  I've spent several weeks now trying to figure out what was missed and searched so many forums, but all their suggestions get me no where.  Users are using the site now (using both OneDrive and Project Server) with no issues, it's mainly the `Newfeed` and Personal sites that are causing the issues.

Ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you extended your application to internet zone ? when you extend it to internet zone, a separate web application gets created and all the links are relative to this internet web application.

Comment: No I haven't done that one... hadn't found much info on it so was reluctant to do it and create further issues.  Any tips in particular on doing this?